# is there a good source for critical study of shabbat zemirot?

Tags: books-generally, product-recommendation, shabbat-songs

The Shabbat Zemirot are written as poetry/songs, and as such, can be kind of cryptic. (See questions tagged "[shabbat-songs](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shabbat-songs)" for examples of questions about certain phrases in the songs.

Is there a source which explains and elucidates the sometimes cryptic verses (Much like [this sefer](http://hebrewbooks.org/49117) explains some of the more cryptic passages in the Selichot prayers)?

Comment: Here's several sefarim available online that do have commentaries on the zemirot, but I don't know if they focus on the individual sentences or just on the history and sources of the zemirot: --- http://hebrewbooks.org/3992 ---- http://hebrewbooks.org/33572 --- http://hebrewbooks.org/48000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be one such source:

[Mateh Yehuda](http://books.google.com/books?id=ZJ8tAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA43&lpg=PA43&dq=%D7%95%D7%97%D7%99%D7%AA%20%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9D&source=bl&ots=kZyH5QOA81&sig=QsepAU0LF89-wc8gcRVPF838ziU&hl=en&ei=eR-_ToXFMaP40gGtkP3uBg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=6&ved=0CEYQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=%D7%95%D7%97%D7%99%D7%AA%20%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9D&f=false) has a running commentary on Zemiros. I don't know how good it is, though.

Comment: Your link led me to this: http://www.klinebooks.com/cgi-bin/kline/20241.html?id=JGfKZM3L - and the sefer you linked to also has the Pirchei Shoshanim (for example - http://books.google.com/books?id=ZJ8tAAAAYAAJ&lpg=PA43&ots=kZyH5QOA81&dq=%D7%95%D7%97%D7%99%D7%AA%20%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9D&pg=PA99#v=onepage&q&f=true)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest this sefer in particular if anyone can find it online it would be appreciated

[Otzar Hateffilos](http://www.zbermanbooks.com/Page.asp?ID=913866aaca735b055c48328a6c1074c7d146d2af85ba1e45c7fcf415dfe230e1&ProductID=130732&CategoryID=7591)